# DFS in an undirected graph - can it have cross edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Is it possible in an undirected graph for an edge that is leasing to an already visited node to lead towards a vertice that is not an ascendant of the current node?

To be more clear, I want to implement a depth-first search on an undirected graph. If I come across an edge that connects my current vertice with an already-visited one, am I guaranteed to have a path from one to another by iterating through the parent array?

The most natural answer seems to be affirmative. I have yet to find a counter-example. What do you think?

In DFS terminology:

Can an edge be a cross-edge in DFS - an edge that leads to an already discovered node, which is not an ancestor of the origin, in an undirected graph?

Comment: Update: I am only taking into consideration the edges which connect a node with a greater depth with one with a smaller one.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a formal DFS terminology to your question, feel free to roll back if you find it unsatisfying

Comment: by parent you mean immediate parent or ancestor ?

Answer (score 6):

An edge discovered by DFS cannot be a cross edge, if its destination is an already discovered node, it must be a back-edge - so it is leading to an ancestor (in the DFS tree) of the source node.

Proof:

Assume it was not the case, and while in some node `v`you encounter an already discovered node (`u`) that is not one of your 'parents' (in the DFS tree).

Since you discovered the node, there is an edge `(v,u)`.

But the graph is undirected, so the edge is symetrical.

Since `u` was already discovered, you have these options:

1. `u` was discovered and not "closed" yet, in this case, you are basically traversing a subtree which has `u` as a root, and `u` is indeed a parent of `v`.
2. `u` was discovered and closed already. But that's impossible considering you just discovered `v`, and there is an edge `(u,v)`.

Thus an edge that leads to an already discovered edge in an undirected graph, must be a back edge, and cannot be a cross-edge.

Comment: Well, what about the case when v is not 'just' discovered? In other words, what if my search has finished finding certain sub-trees, and then I find an edge that links to a node that was not visited initially, but then gets visited in the mean time? Then, I suppose the neighbor should be part of the node's already-processed subtree, am I right?

Comment: @lbicsi I am not following your question, as I see it - doesn't it fit exactly case 2?

Comment: So your answer to the original question "Can an edge be a cross-edge in DFS..." is "Yes"?

Comment: @beaker No, I edited the question to make it the other-way around without editing my question, let me fix it. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Excellent, that makes much more sense. :)

Comment: Here case 2 maybe should be `u` is the **descendant** of `v`. Because maybe we can choose one root and reach `v` first. Then `v` is chosen to branch `w` (*not choosing `(u,v)` first*) which will reach `u` before `v` reaches `u` (then `u` is one *already discovered* node for `v`). In this case, `u` is the descendant of `v`.

Comment: *To prove that*, assume the subtree `T1` rooted at `u` doesn't have `v` as the ancestor (based on the visiting order of `u,v` and the DFS visiting order [implies preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings), `T1` must be at the left subtree from root compared with `v`). Then at some point when constructing `T1`, we must encounter the case 1 because at that point `v` has not been visited before based on the subtree relative location from root.

Comment: Then based on ["forward and back edges are the same thing" in undirected graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11552/161388), we finish the proof. (For case 2, we can also prove as the following. Since `v` is "was discovered and not "closed" yet", similar to case 1, we have `v` is "indeed a parent of" `u`.)